# CSV FILE generator in C

Tags: c, linux, csv, generator

Is there any C program which I can run on a Linux box, and will create a csv file of given dimensions(rows x columns) and store it on hard disk?

Comment: What is your input data?

Comment: An empty "csv file of given dimensions" doesn't sound very useful. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Since you're just looking to run an existing program, why do you care what it's written in?

Comment: My idea is to just populate the cells into random "double" sized data. No I just thought,I will compile it and ./a.out and voila I will have a csv file. To be frank, I just need to play around and check, what are the possible ways of extreme fast reading of csv files from memory. Kind of you know, "Lorem Ipsum" kind of thing.

Comment: C CSV Parser: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvparser C CSV Writer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvwriter

Answer (score 3):

A CSV file is just a plain text file with Comma Separated Values and you can therefore create it by hand in an plain text editor. There is a specification in [RFC 4180](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

Often the first row is used for column names such as:

```
Name, Account no, Amount
Niels, 1234, $0.99
Thomas, 8888, $10.00
Per, 3454, $9.00
Rasmus, 9412, $99.99
```

A small c program to create an plain and empty CSV file could look like:

```
/*
 * makecsv.c 
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   if( argc != 3) {
      printf("Mandatory arguments: <rows> <cols>\n");
         return 1;
      }

      int row, col;
      for(row = 0; row < atoi(argv[1]); row++) {
         for(col = 0; col < atoi(argv[2]); col++) {
            if(col > 0) {
               printf(", ");
            }
            /* Default values are "row x col" */
            printf("\"%dx%d\"", row, col);
         }
         printf("\r\n");
       }
       return 0;
}
```

I'd compile and run it with the following commands:

```
$ gcc -o makecvs makecsv.c 
$ ./makecvs 3 4
"0x0", "0x1", "0x2", "0x3"
"1x0", "1x1", "1x2", "1x3"
"2x0", "2x1", "2x2", "2x3"

$
```

To place the output in a file "the unix way", pipe the output to file using the following commands:

```
$ ./makecvs 3 4 > myFile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an existing utility you're probably on the wrong site, but something like this would print an empty CSV file with double-quoted cells and no header row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols-1; ++j) {
        printf("\"\",");
    }
    printf("\"\"\n");
}
```

Taking some arbitrary data and turning it into a CSV file is harder. First, what's the input data format? Second, escape the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did a search and came up with:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/

So this is but one example of a "library" for csv handling. It  might be worth a look into glib and maybe apr and see if they do have something in there libraries also. Or you can do it "by hand" as suggested here.